# What is NSParameterAssert?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

What is `NSParameterAssert`?

Can anyone explain with example?

Answer (score 117):

It is a simple way to test that a method's parameter is not `nil` or not 0. So basically, you use it to create a precondition, stating that some parameter must be set. If it is not set, the macro causes the application to abort and generates an error on that line. So:

```
- (void)someMethod:(id)someObjectThatMustNotBeNil
{
  // Make sure that someObjectThatMustNotBeNil is really not nil
  NSParameterAssert( someObjectThatMustNotBeNil );
  // Okay, now do things
}
```

Pre-conditions are a simple way to ensure that methods/API are being called correctly by the programmer. The idea is that if a programmer violates the precondition, the application terminates early--hopefully during debugging and basic testing.

`NSParameterAssert` can be used to test that any expression evaluates to be true, however, so you can use it like this as well:

```
NSParameterAssert( index >= 0 ); // ensure no negative index is supplied
```

[Apple's documentation for the NSParameterAssert() macro](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsparameterassert?language=occ)

Comment: Make sure to catch exceptions in your code, otherwise if the Assert is true, it'll crash your app.

Comment: @senthilmuthu It's not exactly like an if statement. They're similar in that they can evaluate an expression, but an if statement is used for program flow control, whereas NSParameterAssert, like Jason Coco's answer explains, will terminate the app if the evaluation results in true. If statements don't do that.

Comment: @lucius: Asserts are not to be used for checking conditions in a distributed application, they are there to catch errors during development.  Causing something to crash on a bad condition (like an unconnected outlet to a Nib), rather than fail silently, lets you find problems early.  Many people disable these at distribution time through macros or #ifdefs.

Comment: @lucius - The goal is to cause the application to abort when preconditions are not met. This lets the programmer know immediately that s/he has done something wrong. To ensure that assertions in Cocoa are not evaluated you can define the NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS macro. This disables them, but the idea is to keep side effects or slow code from executing rather than guarding against crashing--by production, assertions should never trigger if used correctly.

Comment: Is it possible to remove these asserts in a simple way when doing production builds. IMHO these are best used during development to catch programming errors (as mentioned in comment above).

Comment: @JohanKarlsson It is possible, and set by default in the current versions of templates (this goes back pretty far) in the `Release` configuration. You can control this by setting the `ENABLE_NS_ASSERTIONS` build settings in newer versions of Xcode, or by defining the `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS` macro and setting it to 1. In Xcode 5 there is a project setting *Enable Foundation Assertions` that sets the build setting and defaults to `Yes` in `Debug` and `No` in `Release` configurations.