# Objective-c convention for what to do when given nil arguments?

Tags: objective-c, conventions

In objective-c, nil is expected to sort of propagate as opposed to causing an immediate failure. Sending a message to nil (essentially) always results in nil. Is there a similar expectation when sending a nil argument, when that makes no sense?

The particular case I have in mind is essentially the functional `map` method:

```
-(NSArray*) map:(id (^)(id item))projection {
    if (projection == nil) {
        // ?? what to do ??
        // throw exception?
        // return nil?
        // return empty array?
    }

    NSMutableArray* r = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self count]];
    for (id e in self) {
        [r addObject:projection(e)];
    }
    return r;
}
```

Should passing a nil block for projection cause some sort of failure, or some sort of default result?

My personal preference is to fail-fast, but I see objective-C favoring fail-do-nothing in many places. I would appreciate input on what the expected convention is in this sort of case.

*edit*

More specifically, is it acceptable to do this:

```
#define require(expr) \
    if (!(expr)) \
        @throw([NSException exceptionWithName:NSInvalidArgumentException \
                                       reason:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"!require(%@)", (@#expr)] \
                                     userInfo:nil])

-(NSArray*) map:(id (^)(id item))projection {
    require(projection != nil);
    ...
```

Comment: Usually, if `nil` is not a meaningful input (i. e. a method argument is not optional but required or must always be a valid object, etc.) then what Cocoa classes typically do is 1. they ignore error checking and just segfault when passed `nil`, or 2. they throw an `NSInvalidArgumentException`.

Comment: I'd lean to segfault.  The resulting crashtrace is a hell of a lot more useful than the uncaught exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, if your method *requires* that a parameter is not nil, you'd better bail out as soon as possible in case it is.

With this in mind

```
NSParameterAssert(item)
```

is a good practice. It is thoroughly explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521275/what-is-nsparameterassert), but the quick summary is that it throws an `NSInternalInconsistencyException` in case the assertion is not satisfied.

Note that by default the `NSParameterAssert` macro (as well as all the others `NSAssert`-like macros) is removed in release builds, unless you undefine `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS`.

More on the subject is explained [here](http://nshipster.com/nsassertionhandler/).

Answer (score 0):

Since `projection` is a block, not an object, you cannot just ignore checking for it to be nil; you must do the check and react as you need. It's up to you if that reaction means throwing an exception, returning nil, or something else.

Comment: But that is the question. What is the better reaction? Throw an exception, return `nil`, or something else.

Comment: There really isnt any "better reaction" here; it's just in how you want to do things... what works best for the environment you're adding code to.