# When to Set Delegate to NULL

Tags: cocoa-touch, memory-management, delegates

I read a tip here [in a SO best practices posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155964/what-are-best-practices-that-you-use-when-writing-objective-c-and-cocoa):

"If you're passing yourself as a delegate to another object, reset that object's delegate before you dealloc." 
EXAMPLE:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    if (self.someObject.delegate == self) {
        self.someObject.delegate = NULL;
    }
    self.someObject = NULL;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Sounds reasonable, but I'm not sure in what cases I need to do that.
For example, I have a view controller like the one below:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    myTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    myTextField.delegate = self;
}
```

Would I (Should I) set the delegate to NULL in that case, for example:

```
- (void) dealloc {

    if (self.myTextField.delegate == self) {
        self.myTextField.delegate = NULL;
    }
    [myTextField release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: It is worth noting that you should probably be using nil rather than NULL.  [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557582/null-vs-nil-in-objective-c) has some discussion on the matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the object doing the delegating could be getting retained somewhere else and you don't set the delegate to nil there's a chance that your object could be called after it's `dealloc`, which would manifest as a crash. In this specific case you'd probably be okay, but it certainly won't hurt anything to do this.