# Do IBOutlet member vars retain automatically?

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-management, interface-builder

Weird discovery, when I used a drag and drop to make a new IBOutlet, as shown below, not with a @property at all:

```
@interface SkinChoosingView : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView * activityIndicator;
}
```

Xcode inserted a `-release` and set the outlet to nil in `viewDidUnload`. I looked in viewDidLoad though, and no `-retain` was there! This went against everything I know about memory management.

I figure apple must know a thing or two about this stuff though, so is there something behind the scenes happening here? I have never had leaks from these types of IBOutlets, and I've never released them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that it uses "Key-Value Coading", which means it calls `-setValue:forKey:`, which has a ["Default Search Pattern"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/SearchImplementation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000955-137322-BAJCGDAE). For ivars, it does something like `[ivar autorelease]; ivar = [newvalue retain];`.

The "current best practice" is to stick `IBOutlet` on properties instead of ivars (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155964/what-are-best-practices-that-you-use-when-writing-objective-c-and-cocoa/167495#167495)). This makes it obvious what memory management pattern is being used and is more resilient to typos (e.g. if you misspell the ivar).

Comment: I guess that explains where the `retain` comes from. From a test I tried it actually retains three extra times, and releases two extra times with an outlet connected, give the net +1 that prevents it from deallocating.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it automatically retains the outlet for you when loading the NIB file unless you explicitly declare the property associated with the outlet as an `assign`ed property.

And since it retains the outlet for you, you must release in `viewDidUnload` as the outlets will be reloaded by the time next `viewDidLoad` is called.

Comment: But if I didn't declare a property at all, is it still retained? (aside from the one retain it gets by being a subview) I have typically used the declaration above to make weak references, for things I don't need a reference to after the view is gone, and I've never had leaks before.

Comment: Yes, I think I just mentioned that. If you want to make a weak reference, you should declare it as an `assign` property.