# move to next UIVIEW Controller on UI Image view touch event IOS Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have dynamically added image view inside a scroll view

```
  for(NSDictionary *str in slideShowImages){

    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0, 200, 150)];
    NSString *ImageURL = [str objectForKey:@"imageLink"];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageURL]];
    image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

            UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected:)  ];
            singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
            image.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            [image addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

    [documentory addSubview:image];

    x += image.frame.size.width+ 5;
}

documentory.contentSize = CGSizeMake(x, documentory.frame.size.height);
```

when image view touch it call this event

```
-(void)tapDetected:{


}
```

i want to move to another uiview controller when the imageview touch i use story board and since the imageview added dynamically i don't have idea how to do this can anyone help me

PS is there a way that i can use

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {....}
```

in here thank you

Comment: Please check the answer for this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348109/how-can-i-manually-switch-between-uiviewcontrollers-in-storyboard. This may help u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find a way to do that

Drag UIViewController and give a storyboard ID in this case i named as xxx after impliment the action method like below

```
-(void)tapDetected{
    NSLog(@"single Tap on imageview");
    UIStoryboard * storyboard = self.storyboard;

    destinationViewController * detail = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @ "xxx"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController: detail animated: YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to programmatically invoke a push segue, you give the segue a "storyboard id" in Interface Builder and then you can:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:"pushToMyVC" sender:self];
```

OR

If you want to push using navigation controller/ present view controller you can use

```
UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DestinationController"];
```

and push/ present your controller