# iOS - Why can't I use pushViewController the same way twice?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I currently have three view controllers: `ViewController1 ViewController2` and `ViewController3`. I'm trying to pass data between `ViewController1` and `ViewController2` and between `ViewController2` and `ViewController3`.

For example, to pass data `user` holds from `ViewController1` to `ViewController2` I use:

```
ViewController2 *vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc]init];
vc2.user = _user;    

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
```

but if I try to pass `user` from `ViewController2` and `ViewController3`, I can't use the above method...I just get a black view controller appear on screen.

Instead, I tried this and it works:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
ViewController3 *vc3 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vc3Storyboard"];

vc3.user = _user;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc3 animated:YES];
```

Why can't i use the same method i used for vc1 -> vc2?

```
ViewController3 *vc3 = [[ViewController3 alloc]init];
vc3.user = _user;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc3 animated:YES];
```

Comment: Is it possible you made a typo and tried to push a view controller that was already on the navigation stack? This would cause the behavior you describe.

Comment: Definitely seems to be a typo. Can you post that code also.

Comment: @AaronBrager No I didn't! i checked hundreds of times for any errors i mustve done but none...

Comment: Are you sure you instantiated ViewController3 properly (I mean, separate from the method you tried in your second code block)?  Code you post the block of code showing that initial instantiation?

Comment: @LyndseyScott wait, how do i initialize ViewController3 properly? I tried this: `ViewController3 *vc3 = [[ViewController3 alloc]init];`

Comment: @LyndseyScott yeah I could but I'm just wondering why this is not working..

Comment: To be honest, I'm still trying to figure out why it *is* working for you in the first code snippet when you're going from VC1 to VC2, though it makes complete sense that your code in the second snippet works…  Here's a popular stack overflow post about the subject:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8348527/2274694 .  Your VC2 isn't blank is it?

Comment: @LyndseyScott i shall take a look and no its not!

Answer (score 2):

THe reason why you are getting a black screen is because of the method you are using to instantiate it.

```
 ViewController2 *vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc]init];
```

This successfully creates a view controller, but alas, it has no view (you didn't give it one).  The navigation controller will add the view-less view controller to its stack, animating the previous controller out.  Since the default background color of the nav controller is black and the top view controller is nonexistent, then you are experiencing exactly what should appear: nothing.

The reason why your second method works is because the storyboard is instantiating the view controller, but this time it has an actual view:

```
ViewController3 *vc3 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vc3Storyboard"];
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to initiate your viewController as @Wayne Hartman said..

```
ViewController2 * vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];
vc.user = _user;
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Now in your `ViewController2` and `ViewController3` variable "`user`" must have `@Property` and `@synthesize`

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *user;
@synthesize user;
```

And now you can navigate in the `ViewController3` same as `ViewController2`

```
ViewController3 * vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController3"];
vc.user = user;
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

You can find the `ViewController Identifier` from the `Storyboard > Identity inspector`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
        NSMutableArray* array = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
        FirstViewController* viewFirst = [array objectAtIndex:0];
        // Get the third / second or any view controller using its order of insertion / push
        // If you know th order then
        ThirdViewController* thirdView = [array objectAtIndex:2];
        thirdView.view.backgroundColor = viewFirst.view.backgroundColor;
```

If that doesn't work

You can use `NSNotification`for you task