# In Objective-C, why does the variable's type has to be repeated for @property?

Tags: objective-c, properties

For **Objective-C**, in the following header file:

```
@interface Peg : NSObject {
    char color;
}

@property char color;
```

I wonder if the member variable is already said to be a **char** type, then why does the `@property` has to repeat it?  (or else it won't compile).  Couldn't the compiler tell that it is **char**?  It couldn't be anything else, could it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because generaly properties don't have to be related to any declared instance variable of your class. You may have a property and not include a variable into your class header. That's why you have to declare it's type.

Using properties instead of variables makes your headers clean, hiding the implementation.

So, you can just declare a property and then `@synthesize` it

```
@interface Peg : NSObject

@property char color;


@implementation Peg

@synthesize color;

@end
```

Comment: does that mean in general it is more concise to leave out the instance variable?  Leave out or not, there is still a `color` property to use?

Comment: You can leave out the curly braces, too. `@interface Peg : NSObject @property char color;` and so on.

Comment: Here is a talk on proprties and variables,at the bottom http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155964/what-are-best-practices-that-you-use-when-writing-objective-c-and-cocoa

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it's no longer needed, at least when compiling for x64 with clang. If you omit instance variable, `@synthesize` will create one for you.

Answer (score 1):

Just use The following

```
@interface Peg : NSObject {}

@property char color;
```