# What are the coding standards we have to follow in ios development

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am new to ios development. I don't know what are the coding standards we have to follow in ios development. If anyone please suggest me.

Comment: follow apple.developer.com documentation for any help and components to study

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are best practices that you use when writing Objective-C and Cocoa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155964/what-are-best-practices-that-you-use-when-writing-objective-c-and-cocoa)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.pdf

Answer (score 1):

For Coding Standard ios development you can refer these

[Objective-C Coding](http://ironwolf.dangerousgames.com/blog/archives/913)

[cocoadevcentral](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000082.php)

Answer (score 1):

you can go through this site it also has some basics to learn

http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/

Answer (score 0):

Refer apple documentation for [ProgrammingWithObjectiveC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html) this documentation will explain clearly.